# Dictionary assignment overwritten by static values in the loop

Tags: loops, dictionary

I'm trying to calculate the absolute differences between factors of two separate lists. After cross-calculation, the thought process is to save them down into a overall dictionary "kk".

```
kk  = {}
ks = [4,5]
ks2 = [1,2,3,4]
for i in ks:
    diff = {abs(i-j):j  for j in ks2}

    kk[i] = diff
```

This is what I got:

```
{4: {1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1}, 5: {1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1}}
```

As we can see, it is incorrect, as "kk"'s values for both keys are the same...

Comment: Unable to reproduce, your code produces `{4: {3: 1, 2: 2, 1: 3, 0: 4}, 5: {4: 1, 3: 2, 2: 3, 1: 4}}` for me. Try adding a `print(i, diff)` above the `kk[i] =` line, what prints out for you?

Comment: 4 {4: 1, 3: 2, 2: 3, 1: 4}
5 {4: 1, 3: 2, 2: 3, 1: 4}

hmmm. that's what I produced. My Python is 3.6

Comment: @PrintableBao maybe something wrong with your python version, version 3.6 should also give `{4: {3: 1, 2: 2, 1: 3, 0: 4}, 5: {4: 1, 3: 2, 2: 3, 1: 4}}`, try to reproduce your results here so we can see how you get that result: https://repl.it/@downshift/SerenePalatableApplescript